# Change between layouts / many xml files or all layouts in same xml file?

Tags: android, layout, hide, show

Writing a simple program that has 2 windows that switch from one to the other at a button press. At first I managed to do this with two layout files in the same `XML` and just hide one and show the other, but it was near impossible to make a UI this way since the preview window would just bug out and not show what i added to the bottom layer **( pic related: )** https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYjGX.png

So I thought instead, I would make 2 XMLS and have 1 layout in each and now it was easy to make a UI but the code on the other hand does not work.

*java.lang.NullPointerException* @    `btn2.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener()` which doesnt seem to unlogical, **guess u cant listen to a button that isnt active or?**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn1, btn2;
    LinearLayout layHome, layAddNumer;
    RelativeLayout layAddNumber ;
    EditText ph0ne;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        btn1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGoTonumber);
        btn2= (Button)  findViewById(R.id.buttonAddNumber);
        layHome = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layHomeddddddd);
        layAddNumber = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layyPhone);
        ph0ne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNumberText);


        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.phonelayout);

                //layHome.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //layAddNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });





                btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
                    }
                });
```

**xml: This site does not let me add XML files. But `btn1`, `LinearLayout layHome` is in activity:my while `Button btn2,` `RelativeLayout layAddNumber` and `ph0ne` is in my second XML file**

Comment: You should have them in separate files.  Otherwise you're writing extra code.  Plus, you'll end up with more interpreted code that might not actually be shown.

Comment: You should be using two activities instead of changing the layout inside one. Otherwise you end up with..."java.lang.NullPointerException" and other issues. This is rarely a good idea. And this site *does* allow you to add xml files. Just add them in code blocks like you did your Java file

Comment: "guess u cant listen to a button that isnt active or?" you've switched your layout so that button doesn't exist anymore which means `NPE`. Again, the reason using a single Activity is not good

Comment: This is the job done by the android Fragment: 
- put your buttons in the activity with one empty container 
- change the Fragment inside the container when the button is pressed